# Probability and statistics hw

Tags: probability, statistics

On an outing of 100 students to a state park, 40 students brought neither a backpack nor a hat, 50 brought a hat, and 40 brought a backpack. If one of them was randomly chosen, find the probability that (1) he or she brought a backpack or a hat,(2) a backpack and hat

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Here you are expected to show what you have already tried, as nivekgnay stated. We are not here to solve your homework for you, but we will gladly help you through a homework assignment if you put forth effort.

Comment: I  tried finding how much students brought a back pack or hat by doing 100-40 and got 60 students

Comment: @AtifBacchus using that number, do you know how to solve for (1)?

Comment: Would it be 50/60?

Comment: The probability that the randomly selected person is wearing a backpack or hat is equal to  $\frac{\text{# people wearing a backpack or hat}}{\text{# total people}}$. Do you see why this makes sense?

Comment: So the probability of a backpack and a hat is 40/60

Comment: I still don't understand how to approach the first part

Comment: You are choosing a person out of the overall one-hundred.  Your probability then is going to be out of one-hundred.  In general probabilities in an equiprobable sample-space such as this will be of the form (number of good possibilities) divided by (number of total possibilities).

Comment: Would it be 60/100

Comment: @AtifBacchus yes

Comment: What about the second part would it be 40/100

Comment: @AtifBacchus not quite. Recall that you want to find the number of people wearing a backpack and a hat, and then divide that number by the total (100). As mentioned before, there are 60 people wearing a hat or a backpack. Out of those people, 50 people are wearing hats and 40 people are wearing backpacks. Using these numbers, can you deduce the number of people wearing both?

Comment: So it has to be  40/60?

Comment: Or would it be 60/100= 50/100 +40/100 - P(AnB). I get 30/100 have both backpack and hat

Comment: @AtifBacchus you got it!

Comment: Thanks for your help @nivekgnay I appreciate it

Comment: @AtifBacchus no problem, good luck with your homework!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  The given information in the problem is filled out in the table below.  Try filling in the rest of the table.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c||c}&\text{did bring backpack}&\text{did not bring backpack}&\text{total}\\
\hline
\text{did bring hat}&\bullet&\bullet&50\\
\hline
\text{did not bring hat}&\bullet&40&\bullet\\
\hline
\text{total}&40&\bullet&100
\end{array}$